# Database for Portfolio CMS based on Node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, content-management-system

I am pretty new to Node.js, and I am stuck a bit. There is a project a portfolio CMS what popped out of my mind, and actually the simplicity of [Ghost](https://ghost.org/)

Inspired me, that you just download and it works, but I suddenly realized at this case it might not work. Ghost uses SQlight as far as I know.

So my question is, the platform will handle custom pages, so uses will be able to create pages like in Wordpress, will handle blog posts, image gallery and theming.

I was thinking to use MongoDB, but I have some questions.

So people will be available to to create image galleries and insert it to pages as short code (just telling) and my question is.

- Is MongoDB capable for this type of cms?
- Will the embedded data for the image gallery can cause problems in the future or has any limits?

Image gallery example

```
Model.Gallery {
 id:        OjectId,
 name:      Gallery name 1,
 CreatedBy: userId,
 images: [
   {filename: 'image 1'},
   {filename: 'image 2'},
   {filename: 'image 3'},
  ]
}
```

Or would you recommend something else?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for [KeystoneJS](http://keystonejs.com).

*(disclaimer: I am a core contributor)*

It's a mongodb-based CMS for node.js and has a [Yeoman generator](http://github.com/JedWatson/generator-keystone) that you can use to quickly create a blog site with posts, image galleries and an enquiry form. The generator builds basic templates with [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), so it's easy to customise or drop a theme into.

It uses [Jade](http://jade-lang.com) for templates by default, but you can configure it with any template engine (EJS, nunjucks, dust, etc). Same with [LESS](http://lesscss.org) for CSS preprocessing (as Bootstrap does).

While Ghost is very focused in the features it provides (and doesn't give you generic CMS features like Wordpress does), Keystone is more flexible, and its Admin UI is generated based on the models you define (which, in code, look very similar to the example in your question). So you can add other models, and create relationships between them, and the Admin UI will automatically include them.

Image galleries don't really have any limits as in MongoDB you're just storing references to the images, not the files themselves. To make this easy in KeystoneJS we often use a service called Cloudinary, which will handle uploading and resizing for you, and serve the images via a CDN. Keystone also supports Amazon S3 or the local file system if you prefer, though.

For custom pages, you can add these as other templates, or some people define a 'Pages' model for generic content.

Hope this helps!